# Insertion sort program, no output

Tags: c, insertion

This is the simplest insertion sort program.
Unfortunately, it doesn't provide an outcome:
it does prompt the user for the size of the array
and for the list of numbers, but it doesn't do
the sort. I would be grateful for your help!

```
/** Insertion sort **/
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int size, array[80], i, j, element;

    printf("Enter number of elements: \n");
    scanf ("%d", &size);

    printf("Enter %d integers\n", size);

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        element = array[i];
        j = i;

        while (j > 0 && array[j-1] > element)
        {
          array[j] = array[j-1];
          array[j-1] = element;
          j--; 
        }
     }

     printf ("Sorted list in ascending order:\n");

     for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf ("%d", array[i]);

     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Tested with input `5 1 2 3 4 5`, `5 5 4 3 2 1` and `5 8 4 1 5 1` and for all of them this program seemed working fine on [Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/BUS7cUAS8hhokRtw). Can you provide your input?

Comment: `printf ("%d ", array[i]);` print a space after each number

Comment: The program works (MSVC), add a space as commented above.

Comment: Why would adding a space make it show the output? I would have suggested adding a newline at the end instead. The fact that all numbers appear without separators between them ought not make a difference here.

Comment: maybe your stdout is closed or something internal because the code works for me

Comment: Usual DCV for no aparrent debugging attempt.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those confusing moments :)
I have forgotten that there is a '\n' character
in the second printf, after which the user is 
prompted for the list. Therefore, I've kept typing
in numbers in one row, without hitting ENTER; of course,
the program considered that as one number, only one integer
not the list ))) Thank you everyone for replying. 
Sorry for this.